# can I modify ACK field or CRC field in CAN frame?

Tags: can-bus

To generate error on CAN, I've done change data field. But It seems just change numerical things.
I want to know how to modify ACK or CRC field to inject error.
Can I change that field with software?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change that from software, since that part of the message is always constructed on CAN Communication Controller level and down (Physical Layer).

Basically, the ACK field is not set in SW. It is "completed" by other nodes while the message is sent, and the bitstream arrived to the ACK bit slot. 
The CRC is constructed on Communication Controler level, upon the payload the application wishes to send.

So in order to inject such faults in a CAN message, you need a special HIL (Hardware in the Loop) device, which will forcefully overwrite fields of your choosing. 
One such device is a CANSTress from Vector, but there are many others.

**Regarding NACK error**, *you can simulate that without HIL*, if you have a simulation environment.Or, simply do not turn on the other nodes on the cluster, ensuring there is no other node to ACK the message. Beware, **disconnecting CANH and CANL cables will result in a different error type**.

Comment: thanks to answer. Then can I generate other type of error with software? ex) stuffing

Comment: No, neither bit stuffing error can be injected from SW level. These 5 errors are Protocol specific errors. If we think about the CAN protocol as the UPS service, the UPS trucks are the CAN frames (messages) and you, the client is the SW/Application. 
You hand over the packet to them, fill out the papers, but thats it. You cannot puncture their truck tires, sabotage engine etc... Meaning you cannot inject the 5 CAN errors. 
You can obtain the bit stuffing error (and bit monitoring and format error also) if you set mingle with the baudrate of individual nodes.Or send CAN FD frame instead CANHD

Comment: Besides, if you could do these from SW level, CAN protocol would not be that foolproof as it claims to be.